# How can I print out a map[string]interface{} as json?

Tags: go

I have a problem with formatting when using `sqlx`

```
rows, err = db.Queryx(query)
for rows.Next() {
    results := make(map[string]interface{})
    err = rows.MapScan(results)
    fmt.Fprintf(w,"%#v \n", results)
}
```

The output when using **%#v**

```
fmt.Fprintf(w,"%#v \n", results)
```

> map[string]interface {}{"USER_ID”:”JD”, "USER_NAME”:”John Doe”}
>
> map[string]interface {}{"USER_ID”:”JAD”, "USER_NAME”:”Jane Doe”}
>
> map[string]interface {}{"USER_ID”:”DD”, "USER_NAME”:”Donald Duck”}

Using only **%v**

```
fmt.Fprintf(w,"%v \n", results)
```

> map[USER_ID:JD USER_NAME:John Doe]
>
> map[USER_ID:JAD USER_NAME:Jane Doe]
>
> map[USER_ID:DD USER_NAME:Donald Duck]

The desired output is to get rid of **map[string]interface {}**

> {"USER_ID”:”JD”, "USER_NAME”:”John Doe”}
>
> {"USER_ID”:”JAD”, "USER_NAME”:”Jane Doe”}
>
> {"USER_ID”:”DD”, "USER_NAME”:”Donald Duck”}

Is this possible?

**EDIT USING JSON**

According to @Timothy Jones I have updated the main code and it work as expected. Except that the result is printed to the TERMINAL and not browser.

```
rows, err = db.Queryx(query)
  for rows.Next() {
    results := make(map[string]interface{})
    err = rows.MapScan(results)
    if err := enc.Encode(results); err != nil {
      fmt.Fprintf(w,"%s\n", results)
    }
  }
```

> {"USER_ID”:”JD”,”USER_NAME”:”John Doe”}
>
> {"USER_ID”:”JAD”,”USER_NAME”:”Jane Doe”}
>
> {"USER_ID”:”DD”,”USER_NAME”:”Donald Duck”}

Removing the error handling just to test. It shows wrong results, but are printed to the BROWSER as it should.

```
rows, err = db.Queryx(query)
for rows.Next() {
  results := make(map[string]interface{})
  err = rows.MapScan(results)
  enc.Encode(results)
  fmt.Fprintf(w,"%s\n", results)
}
```

> map[USER_ID:JD USER_NAME:John Doe]
>
> map[USER_ID:JAD USER_NAME:Jane Doe]
>
> map[USER_ID:DD USER_NAME:Donald Duck]

One question remains. How do I print the correct result to the BROWSER?

Comment: You'll have to do it yourself, instead of depending on a printf verb

Comment: @Flimzy Can you give an example?

Comment: Looks like what you want happens to be JSON encoding, so use the encoding/json package.

Comment: @Peter Any link or hint how to use encoding/json together with sqlx?

Comment: This has nothing to do with sqlx. You want to format a map[string]interface{}. The fact that you fill it with MapScan is irrelevant. encoding/json is [documented on golang.org](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/), like every other package in the standard library.

Comment: I am stuck being a total newbie. Something like     json.Unmarshal([]byte(results]), &results). Or can you be more specific?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to format your output as JSON, it's better to use the [`json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package.  There's a well-written introduction to json handling [in this blog post](https://blog.golang.org/json-and-go), but generally the `Marshal` function is happy to take a map of `map[string]interface{}` where `interface{}` is any other type that it is able to marshal:

```
b, err := json.Marshal(m)
```

This returns a byte array, so you'll need to convert it to a string:

```
m := map[string]string{
    "USER_ID":"JD", 
    "USER_NAME":"John Doe",
}
b, err := json.Marshal(m)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println(string(b))
```

https://play.golang.org/p/rffsuI4BL35

However, since you know that you're just going to print out the encoded result, it's probably better to use a streamed encoder:

```
m := map[string]string{
    "USER_ID":"JD", 
    "USER_NAME":"John Doe",
}
enc := json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout)

if err := enc.Encode(m); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/l2-BOUK3yn9

For your code, it looks like this:

```
enc := json.NewEncoder(w)
rows, err = db.Queryx(query)
// Note: you should check err here

for rows.Next() {
    results := make(map[string]interface{})
    err = rows.MapScan(results)
    // Note: You should check err here       

    if err := enc.Encode(results); err != nil {
         // Whatever you want to do in an encoding error
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this exhaustive answer!  It sure points me in the right direction, but there still are some minor issues. Look at my updated question.

Comment: Your updated question is unrelated to your initial question, I recommend you ask a new question.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that you were writing to a specific `Writer` in your original question. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Yes! it works better. Thank you! But numeric values does not encode correct: "QTY":"MS4wMA==". How come?

Comment: Though this not solved my entire problem, it was an exact answer to my question. Thank you!